# Vue.js cast as json not working

Tags: json, vue.js

Whats the syntax to cast data to json in vue.js

I've been trying to follow the laracast episode https://laracasts.com/series/learning-vuejs/episodes/8  where the data is cast to json using:

```
 <pre>
            {{ $data | json }}
 </pre>
```

However I get the following error: `Use of undefined constant json - assumed 'json'`

I'm using Vue.js v1.0.13, the one in the episode is an older version but I can't seem to find the correct syntax?

Comment: That is not the problem with `vuejs`. The error messages seems to be thrown from PHP.

Comment: it's not a php error. I've managed to fix it by prepending `@{{ $data | json }}`

Comment: Could you, please, create example on https://jsfiddle.net/ or codepen.io. You have issue in code. It's hard to find issue in code based only on template. Check this out. `json` filter work as expected. https://jsfiddle.net/0f1LLdgz/

Answer (score 2):

For me the issue was that the `@{{ entity | json }}` was outside of my Vue `el` element. Moving it inside fixed it.